# PVCs and multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a small Saas App that customers can sign up for, and they get their own instance completely separated from the rest of the clients. It's a simple REST API, with a DB (postgres) and caddy that gets deployed using a docker-compose.

This works fine, but requires me to create the VPS, deploy the different services, and essentially is really hard to manage as I most of the work is manual.

I have decided to use kubernetes, and I have gotten to the point where I can create a separate instance of the system on it's own, isolated namespace for each client, fully automated. This creates the different deployments, services, and pods. Also, I create a PVC for each namespace/client.

The issue has to do with Persistent Volume Claims, and how they work in namespaces. As I want to keep the data completely separate from other instances, I wanted to create a PVC for each client, so that only the DB from that client can access it (and the server, as it requires some data to be written to disk).

This works fine in minikube, but the issue comes with the hosting provider. I use DigitalOcean's managed cluster and they do not allow multiple PVCs to be created, therefore making it impossible to achieve the level of isolation that I want. They allow you to mount a block storage (whatever size you need), and then use it. This would mean that the data is all stored on the "same disk", and all namespaces can access it.

My question is: Is there a way to achieve the same level of isolation, i.e. separate the mount points for each of the DB instances, in such a way that I can still achieve (or at least get close) to the level of separation that I require? The idea would be something along the lines of:

```
/pvc-root
   /client1
      /server
      /db
   /client2
      /server
      /db
...
```

This is what I have for now:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: database-claim
  name: database-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: database
  name: database
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "5432"
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: database
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: database
  name: database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: db_name
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: db_password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: db_user
        image: postgres:10
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: database-claim
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: database-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: database-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: server
  name: server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: server
  name: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: server
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: database
        - name: DB_NAME
          value: db_name
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: db_password
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          value: db_user
        image: <REDACTED>
        name: server-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes: null
```

**EDIT Feb 02, 2021**

I have been in contact with DO's customer support and they clarified a few things:

- You need to manually attach a volume to the cluster, so the PVC deployment file is ignored. The volume is then mounted and available to the cluster but NOT in a ReadWriteMany config, which could have served this case quite well
- They provide an API, so in theory I could create the volume (for each client) programmatically and then attach a volume for a specific client, keeping a ReadWriteOnce
- This of course locks me in to them as a vendor, and makes things a bit harder to configure and migrate

I am still looking for suggestions whether this is the correct approach for my case. If you have a better way let me know!

in theory this should be achievabe

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _" they do not allow multiple PVCs to be created"_ ?

Comment: Sorry, the sentence is ambiguous. What I mean is that you need to create a Volume, attach it to the cluster and then you can access it. So a bit tedious. Look at the edit for some more info

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve the same level of isolation, i.e. separate the mount points for each of the DB instances, in such a way that I can still achieve (or at least get close) to the level of separation that I require?

Don't run a production database with a *single volume*. You want to run a database with some form of replication, in case a volume or node crash.

Either run the database in a *distributed setup* e.g. using [Crunchy PostgreSQL for Kubernetes](https://www.crunchydata.com/products/crunchy-postgresql-for-kubernetes/) or use a *managed database* e.g. [DigitalOcean Managed Database](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases/)

Within that DBMS, create [logical databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/manage-ag-createdb.html) or [schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createschema.html) for each customer - if you really need that strong isolation. Hint: it is probably easier to maintain with less isolation e.g. using multi-tenancy within the tables.

Comment: Thanks but the application has been designed as a single tenant application, and reverting to a multi-tenant system would require an almost full rewrite. Also, I do not want to rely on managed instances but I want to have full control of the system. All I am trying to do is replicate the docker-compose setup I had with kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's a solution that may bode well for your use case - if you still haven't found a solution.

Create a highly available `NFS/CEPH` server then export that in a way that your pods can attach to it.  Then create `PV`'s and `PVC`'s as you'd like and bypass all that DO blockage.

You have an application very similar to what you describe I support and I went with a highly available `NFS` server using `DRBD`, `Corosync`, and `Pacemaker` and it all works as expected.  No issues so far.